# numpy.choose 32 choice limitation

Tags: python, numpy

Low and behold, I ran into a regression in numpy.choose after upgrading to 1.5.1.  Past versions (and numeric) supported an, as far as I could tell, unlimited number of potential choices.  The "new" choose is limited to 32.  [Here is a post](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-July/057831.html) where another user laments the regression.

I have a list with 100 choices (0-99) that I was using to modify an array.  As a work around, I am using the following code.  Understandably, it is 7 times slower than using choose.  I am not a C programmer, and while I would to get in an fix the numpy issue, I wonder what other potentially faster work arounds exist.  Thoughts?

```
d={...} #A dictionary with my keys and their new mappings
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    array[array==key]=value
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the keys of `d` are the numbers 0 to 99?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather that `d` has the keys `0` to `99`.  In that case, the solution is really simple.  First, write the values of `d` in a NumPy array `values`, in a way that `d[i] == values[i]` – this seems to be the natural data structure for these values anyway.  Then you can access the new array with the values replaced by

```
values[array]
```

If you want to modify `array` in place, simply do

```
array[:] = values[array]
```

Comment: What is the array[:] functionality called?  I want to learn more about exactly what is happening from the numpy documentation.

Comment: @Jzl5325: This is slicing the whole array.  It's actually not something specific to NumPy, but to Python in general.  Check the official Python tutorial, it explains how slicing works.

Comment: Gotcha.  I had not used just [:] before, but can see a ton of use.  The = syntax is what is throwing me (though it works beautifully).  We are not assigning a variable, but running an if statement through an =.  It reads "if value in the input array is equal to the index in the values array, replace the input array number with the value number"? Thanks!

Comment: @Jzl5325: It's `values[array]` that is selecting the values.  For an integer `i`, `values[i]` selects the value `i` should be translated to.  Now imagine doing this for the whole array at once, and you get `values[array]`.  The assignment is pretty straight-forward – it simply copies all the values from the new array created by `values[array]` into the old array.

Answer (score 3):

In the Numpy documentation, there is an example of how a simplified version of the choose function could look like.

> [...] this function is less simple than it might seem from the
>   following code description (below ndi = numpy.lib.index_tricks):
>
> ```
> np.choose(a,c) == np.array([c[a[I]][I] for I in ndi.ndindex(a.shape)]).
> ```

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html

Putting this into a function could look like this:

```
import numpy

def choose(selector, choices):
    """
    A simplified version of the numpy choose function to workaround the 32
    choices limit.
    """
    return numpy.array([choices[selector[idx]][idx] for idx in numpy.lib.index_tricks.ndindex(selector.shape)]).reshape(selector.shape)
```

I am not sure how this translates in terms of efficiency and when exactly this breaks down when compared to the `numpy.choose` function. But it worked fine for me. Note that the patched function assumes that the entries in the choices are subscriptable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about efficiency and it's not in-place (nb: I don't use numpy that often - so somewhat rusty):

```
import numpy as np

d = {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 20}
data = np.array([[1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]])
new_data = np.array([d.get(i, i) for i in data.flat]).reshape(data.shape) # adapt for list/other
```

Comment: The whole point of NumPy is to avoid Python loops in favour of implicit loops implemented in C.  This code iterates over ever single value, so it's certainly not very fast.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I'm aware of how numpy works. `.flat` is low level, a generation of an array from a list is low level, a re-shape isn't complex, so, as a kludge it's possibly not the worse one could come up with. It's also infinitely faster on 33 choices :)

Comment: If the array is huge, it might very well be slower than the original code even for 33 choices.

Answer (score 0):

When colorizing microscopy images of mouse embryos I ran into a need for
a `choose` implementation where the number of choices was in the hundreds
(hundreds of mouse embryo cells).

https://github.com/flatironinstitute/mouse_embryo_labeller

As I was not sure whether the above suggestions were general or fast
I wrote this alternative:

```
import numpy as np

def big_choose(indices, choices):
    "Alternate to np.choose that supports more than 30 choices."
    indices = np.array(indices)
    if (indices.max() <= 30) or (len(choices) <= 31):
        # optimized fallback
        choices = choices[:31]
        return np.choose(indices, choices)
    result = 0
    while (len(choices) > 0) and not np.all(indices == -1):
        these_choices = choices[:30]
        remaining_choices = choices[30:]
        shifted_indices = indices + 1
        too_large_indices = (shifted_indices > 30).astype(np.int)
        clamped_indices = np.choose(too_large_indices, [shifted_indices, 0])
        choices_with_default = [result] + list(these_choices)
        result = np.choose(clamped_indices, choices_with_default)
        choices = remaining_choices
        if len(choices) > 0:
            indices = indices - 30
            too_small = (indices < -1).astype(np.int)
            indices = np.choose(too_small, [indices, -1])
    return result
```

Note that the generalized function uses the underlying implementation
when it can.

Comment: fyi: I made this into a pull request to numpy because it might be generally useful: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20001/files